# Protractor using Expected Condition as parameter in TypeScript callback functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I'm trying to pass an ExpectedConditions function as a parameter to a function.

This way I could interchange the different conditions, and I wouldn't have to create functions for each one for easier usage.

The problem is, that Protractor throws an error:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined

and it points to the ExpectedConditions implementation.

Code that could reproduce the issue and shows my intent:

```
import { browser, by, element, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions, until } from 'protractor';

describe('wait on google page', () => {

    const searchBtn = element.all(by.name('btnK')).last()

    beforeEach(() => {
        browser.get('https://www.google.com');
    });

    it('should work with until callback', () => {
        callbackWait(until.elementIsVisible, searchBtn)
    });

    it('should work with ExpectedConditions', () => {
        browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchBtn), 1_000)
    });

    it('should work with EC callback', () => {
        callbackWait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf, searchBtn)
    });

});

function callbackWait(condition, element: ElementFinder) {
    browser.wait(condition(element.getWebElement()), 1_000)
}
```

With `until.elementIsVisible` the code works as intended, its the same if I use the ExpectedCondition in the `browser.wait()`, the error occurs if I use the ExpectedCondition as I use the `until.elementIsVisible`.

Any suggestions for a workaround or tip for what did I do wrong?

npm package.json dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "jasmine": "^3.3.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
```

Comment: Please show the function code of  `until.elementIsVisible`.

Comment: The `until.elementIsVisible` code fragment is from the webdriver-js module that the protractor wraps around:
[until.elementIsVisible source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the `this`, look at the `visibilityOf` definition at following or from [github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L393)

```
  visibilityOf(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function {
    return this.and(this.presenceOf(elementFinder), () => {
      return elementFinder.isDisplayed().then(passBoolean, falseIfMissing);
    });
  }
```

As you see there is `this.and`.

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(searchBtn)
//if you call visibilityOf() in one line, the `this` is not null/undefined
//`this` has value, it's `ExpectedConditions` itself.

// but if you do as following

function callbackWait(condition, ele) {
    browser.wait(condition(ele), 1000)
}

var btn = element(by.css('#id'))
var cond1 = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
callbackWait(cond1, btn)

// after you assign function `visibilityOf` to cond1
// the `this` value missed, it will becomes undefined.
// thus when you call cond1(ele) inside callbackWait, 
// this.and reports: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined
```

To fix the `this` value missing issue, you need to use `bind()` to bind a value to 'this'.

```
it('should work with EC callback', () => {
    let cond = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf.bind(ExpectedConditions);
    // assign ExpectedConditions back to `this` via bind()
    callbackWait(cond, searchBtn)
});
```

Except `this` issue, your `callbackWait()` also has issue.

```
// for ExpectedConditions.xxxx, it's only accept ElementFinder type
// if parameter: condition value like ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
function callbackWait(condition, element: any) {
    browser.wait(condition(element), 1000)
}

// but for webdirver.util.xxxx, it's only accept WebEelment type
// if parameter: condition value like util.elementIsVisible
function callbackWait(condition, element: any) {
    browser.wait(condition(element.getWebElement()), 1000)
}
```

Actually, `ExpectedConditions` supply all features of `/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js`, thus no need to mix them to use in script.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works as a charm!
I had a notion that it has to do something with apply/bind/call, but I am quite a beginner in TS so I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: The reason for the `/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js` block was to provide an example, that it somehow works without a `bind()`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have until defined similarly to
`import {ExpectedConditions as until} from 'protractor'`
This means that `ExpectedConditions.stuff` and `until.stuff` are basically the exact same.
However, `elementIsVisible` is not an ExpectedCondition. You are correct in using `visibilityOf`.
Check out the [Expected Conditions Documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Comment: No, the until is from the basic webdriver-js module. The import are :
`import { browser, by, element, ElementFinder, ExpectedConditions, until } from 'protractor';`
(I edited the question as well.)